# Not able to retrieve images in jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp, file-upload

display.jsp

```
        <body>    
        <h1>Displaying Image</h1>
        <%
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
              session.setAttribute("username", auth.getName());
        %>

            <c:forEach var="imageName" items="${files}">
                ${username}${imageName}
                <img src="../images/${username}/${imageName}"/>
            </c:forEach>    
        </body>
```

Saving the images in path

```
(C:\workspace\fileupload\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\images\user1\)
```

in code using .....

```
new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("../")+"/images"+"/"+auth.getName());
```

reaching to the deployed webfolder and then coming one step back(as using here ../) then creating a folder "images" then inside images creating a folder with the name of user (as using here +"/"+auth.getName()), saving the images successfully.But while retrieving these image, i tried the code written in jsp, but it is not working.here in jsp , i checked for  ${username} and ${imageName} both are retrieving correct values from controller, means there is not any issue with controller side, but while constructing the url for retrieving image, it is getting wrong somewhere.Could someone plz help to get it right

src="../images/${username}/${imageName}"

Comment: try fully qualified name

Comment: bad idea !! how can i use fully qualified name in the context of server

Answer (score 0):

Keep your `Image` folder in the place where `display.jsp` is stored and try again.

Comment: i want to keep my image folder out of the webfolder becoz if m not doing so, every time , when i ll do run on server, the image folder will gone, and every time it create a new folder deleting the existing one along with webfolder